# Javascript currying vs method chaining

Tags: javascript, currying, method-chaining

From what I have understood:

Currying - functions returning functions

```
string.capitalize(1)('character')('at the end')
```

Method chaining - methods returning objects

```
string.lowercase.capitalize.uppercase
```

Is this understanding correct?

If so, are there cases one of them is better than the other?

Cause it seems to me that method chaining is better and more readable. You also have autocompletion showing what methods you can use if you hit "dot" and it will show all the arguments you can pass.

Comment: JavaScript does not support currying natively (it can be emulated with closures, but.. also, the example posted does not really look like a sensible curry :-) and thus just chaining (which is not orthogonal to currying) is normally used. A big "reason" to curry is to be able to use *partially applied* functions -- once again, doable just with closures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A better equivalent of currying would be the Builder design pattern.

Ergo, you would do something like:

`myObject.setIndexRangeToEffect(1,1).setTextTransformation(UPPERCASE).execute();`

At any point before calling `execute`, you essentially have a "curried" action object.

Comment: Thank you! I was starting to feel currying is like builder pattern and I also thought I'm crazy.

Comment: You nailed it!!